# How to avoid propagation of type constraints?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, type-constraints

In the underlying use case I'm dealing with different serialization formats and depending on the configured format (via DI) a certain factory is used. However, I think I run into a more general problem here, therefore I simplified the following use case.

Suppose I have a simple interface with a generic method:

```
public interface IProducerFactory
{
    public IProducer<T> CreateProducer<T>();
}
```

Now I have a concrete implementation `ProducerFactoryA`, which works just fine. Even though `BuilderA` comes from an external library, I can easily create an instantiation implementing `IProducer<T>`:

```
public class ProducerFactoryA : IProducerFactory
{
    public IProducer<T> CreateProducer<T>()
    {
        // some configuration ...
        return new BuilderA<T>().Build();
    }
}
```

For `ProducerFactoryB`, I need to use the external library `BuilderB`. However, `BuilderB` has type constraints, which would require me to add them to the interface `IProducerFactory` and basically everywhere where I want to use it:

```
public class ProducerFactoryB : IProducerFactory
{
    public IProducer<T> CreateProducer<T>()
        where T : ISomeConstraint, new()
    {
        // some configuration ...
        return new BuilderB<T>().Build();
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I avoid such a situation? I clearly don't want `ISomeConstraint` which comes from an external library to be part of my interface and propagate this type throughout my codebase. Furthermore, it would also break `ProducerFactoryA`.

Is there a way to check these constraints to satisfy the compiler without adding them on the method/interface level?

Answer (score 1):

The `IProducerFactory` makes a promise that any implementation can produce **any** kind of object, without restrictions. So if you want restrictions you would need to propagate them or get rid of them.

An alternative would be to declare the generic type as part of the interface:

```
public interface IProducerFactory<T>
{
    public IProducer<T> CreateProducer();
}

public class ProducerFactoryB : IProducerFactory<ISomeConstraint>
{
    public IProducer<ISomeConstraint> CreateProducer()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This makes a much weaker promise, i.e. if you somehow get a producer factory for a specific type, it can create producers of that type. You could also mix the patterns, and have one interface that can create producers for any type, and one that can only create specific types.